# Why image in template doesn't showing? UWP

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp

This is part of my code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="lbSongsTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" - " Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=root1, Path=DataContext.DownloadSong}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Grid.Column="3" Padding="0" Margin="0"  BorderThickness="0" Width="20" Height="20">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="Images/like.jpg" Height="20" Width="20" />
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Button have image in content property. Why this image doesn't showing?
If button is not templated its work fine.

Comment: I understand you want to use your own Image. But why not use [SymbolIcons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn252842)

Comment: Because it button must have jpeg image.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, please provide more details? Or is it possible to share your demo?